# How to find which file is being loaded by a (relative path) require() without looking through all the folders in the include_path

Tags: php, logging, include, include-path

I have a script installed on multiple servers with the first line being:

```
require_once 'MDB2.php';
```

On some servers this file is being found from a shared folder somewhere, but on others the file isn't found. Is there any quick way to log or output which files (ie which folder they are in) are being loaded by a require or include call, without having to determine the include_path value and search through all the folders as specified by that value?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [include documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) on the PHP site there doesn't appear to be a faster way than the following:

```
<?php

function include_which($filename) {
    $dirs = explode(':', ini_get('include_path'));
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        if (is_file("{$dir}/{$filename}")) {
            return "{$dir}/{$filename}";
        }
    }
}
```